# How Fittig reaction gives good yield if phenyl cations are unstable?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I am confused,after reading from NCERT text that phenyl cations are unstable due several reasons like the carbon in phenyl group is sp2 hybridized,resonance structures do not stabilizes the phenyl cation.But then,in Fittig reaction we do have phenyl cations as intermediate.For example in a reaction between two molecules of chloro benzene and sodium metal we get a diphenyl molecule.Here we have two phenyl cation generated (if i am right).Then what factor stabilizes the phenyl cation?If there is any error in the theoretical aspect of the question please help me correct it as i am not quite sure about the mechanism.

I would be very much glad to accept an answer with some thermodynamical data like the bond enthalpies of C-Cl bond and newly formed product's bond enthalpy that is C-C bond enthalpy(in the case of diphenyl)and the total realease in energy.

Comment: Then, probably, we don't have phenyl cations as intermediates?

Comment: @IvanNeretin  so what you are saying is that phenyl cations are not being generated?right? –

Comment: The Sandmeyer reaction involves the formation of aryl cations. Although they are very high energy they are formed in this reaction because nitrogen (the leaving group) is also formed in the process. Since nitrogen is an extremely stable molecule it drives the formation of the phenyl cation..

Comment: @ron yeah that would be correct.But in wurtz reaction what you are saying would be that the formation of NaCl releases lot of energy and the C-Cl sp2 hybridised bond will broken as the energy released  by formation of NaCl is greater than the bond enthalpy of C-Cl bond.correct?Would you provide me with the bond enthalpy of C-Cl bond in chloro benzene as i didn't get any result from internet.

Comment: I don't know if the Wurtz reaction involves cations, but the reaction involves solid sodium and complex things can take place on a metal surface.

Comment: @ron in some internet  sites i found that a phenyl anion being generated and in some it says it proceeds with free radical mechanism.But i feel that if in any case the C-Cl bond is broken a phenyl cation would be generated as chlorine is more electronegative.

Comment: The [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wurtz%E2%80%93Fittig_reaction) page for the Wurtz-Fittig reaction suggests the alkyl halide is reduced twice to the organosodium species, which undergoes electrophilic attack on the aryl halide.

Answer (score 1):

The most probable [mechanism for Wurtz reaction](http://www.adichemistry.com/organic/namedreactions/wurtz/wurtz-reaction-1.html) or Fittig reaction involves formation of organic free radicals and not cations. Like in Wurtz reaction, phenyl free radicals are formed in Fittig too.

Comment: I checked out the site you mentioned.But it doesn't have any data regarding    the mechanism for halobenzene.Rather it has only data regarding aliphatic halides (that is wurtz reaction and not fittig reaction),which probably won't be the answer as both involves completely different type of molecules.One is aromatic and other is aliphatic and C-X bond these two have different bond enthalpy(if i am right).

Comment: Expecting different mechanisms for different molecules is good. However, what is important is in both the cases, Na is used. It is a good reducing agent and can provide electron equally well to aliphatic and aromatic compounds. One more aspect is the C-X bond in aromatic compounds is stronger also implies, X cannot leave as X-